# How can I ask for the user's DisplayName and store it in $user

Tags: powershell

I'm just starting my first PowerShell script for our employee exits.

Right now, I'm only looking for help with: asking for the user's DisplayName and storing it as $user.

I've tried a few variations of something like this:

```
$user = Try {
    Get-ADUser Read-Host 'Who is exiting'
}
Catch {
    -WriteLog 'Could not find DisplayName'
}
```

But am obviously not getting it right. I'd like to then be able to pipe it into something like what's below (of course not as is, I'd clean it up, but that's where I'm heading).

```
| $_.Disable-ADAccount $user 

| $_.Set-ADAccountPassword $user -AccountPassword $password

| $_.Get-ADUser $user -properties manager #I only want to display the user's manager so I don't have to go find it

| $_.Get-ADGroup * | Remove-AD-Group *#remove them from all groups except DomainUser and add them to our termed user group
```

Please don't respond with this portion yet, I'd like to struggle my way through as much of this as I can but am having a hard time asking for the user's lastname, firstname and storing it as $user.

I greatly appreciate your time!

Comment: Downvoted because this question makes no sense. Pls rephrase it so we can get an idea of what it is you're struggling with.

Comment: Is this half python and half powershell?

Comment: Wow, I'm really not as dumb as that looked. Was a long day and half asleep when I copied the wrong code. This is a PowerShell script. Thank you.

Comment: Going forward I will be sure to better prepare myself before asking a useless question. Was not my intention. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK let's start with the basics:

What is an cmdlet (comandlet)? You have used multiple of them. For example `Get-ADUser` and `Read-Host`. They consist of a *Verb* and a *Noun* (most of the time the words are neither verb nor noun in a gramaticle way but who cares):
`Read` = Verb
`Host` = Noun
`Read-Host` = cmdlet

Every cmdlet does something, like reading what you type, and most of them return the results as objects. Objects like strings, integers, hashtables or other crazy sh***...
If you don't store the output in a variable it will be printed to screen most of the time, so better save it for later:

```
$MyBrandNewString = Read-Host -Prompt 'Who let the dogs out?'
```

Variables begin with a `$` the rest of the name is up to you.
If you want to use the ouput of one cmdlet in another one you can either use the variable:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $MyBrandNewString
```

or put the first cmdlet in braces so that it's executed first (The braces are replaced by the output object of the cmdlet so to say):

```
Get-ADUser -Identity (Read-Host -Prompt 'Who let the dogs out?')
```

Or (the most cool one and my favorit) you can just pipe the output of one cmdlet to another one concatenating them indefinitly:

```
 Read-Host -Prompt 'Who let the dogs out?' | Get-ADUser
```

You can't just put them behind eachother:

```
Get-ADUser Read-Host
```

And you can't use them as properties of objects:

```
$_.Disable-ADAccount
```

But you can create an object and use that as propertie of another object:

```
$MyBrandNewString.( Read-Host -Prompt 'Write Length')
```

That's enough PowerShell crash course for today. I very highly recomend you to read some tutorials, as all of this is the very very basics of PowerShell. But never give up and soon you will script like there is no tomorow!

Comment: This is perfect thank you! I just started the PowerShell in a month of lunches videos with Don Jones and found The Weekend Scripter by Scripto that also pointed to a lot of great resources. I'll think more closely going forward on how to ask the right questions and make sure I use the built-in help in the console.